# how to use biasedNumberBetween faker?

Tags: php, faker

I am trying to get a number between 1 to 6 with more chances to be close to 1.

i have tried this:

```
<li>{{Faker\Factory::create()->biasedNumberBetween($min = 10, $max = 20, $function = 'unbiased')}}</li>
```

What i am trying to do is to generate a number from 1 to 6 `rand(1,6);` but make the numbers be closer to one as the lower numbers will have more weight than the others.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this ?

```
<?php
function weightedRand($min, $max, $weightedMax) {
$arr = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $arr[] = rand($min, $weightedMax);
}
$arr[] = rand($min, $max);
return $arr[rand(0,10)];
}

echo weightedRand(1,6, 3);
?>
```

numbers below 4 will now be more likely than numbers above :)

Comment: i used this code:                                                                                  $faker = Faker\Factory::create();                                                             $faker->biasedNumberBetween($min = 1, $max = 6, $function = 'Faker\Provider\Biased::linearLow');